# How is replaceChild() supposed to work?

Tags: javascript

I am teaching myself javascript and don't understand the results I am getting from some example code. I have pruned the code for brevity.

The html:

```
<body>
        <h1>firstChild and lastChild Property Lab</h1>
        <hr />
        <form>
            <label>Enter some text to add or replace in the OL element:</label>
            <br />
            <input type="text" name="input" size="50" />
            <br />
            <input type="button" value="Insert at Top"
                    onclick="prepend(this.form)" />
            <input type="button" value="Append to Bottom"
                    onclick="append(this.form)" />
            <br />
            <input type="button" value="Replace First Item"
                    onclick="replaceFirst(this.form)" />
            <input type="button" value="Replace Last Item"
                    onclick="replaceLast(this.form)" />
        </form>
        <ol id="myList">
            <li>Initial Item 1</li>
            <li>Initial Item 2</li>
            <li>Initial Item 3</li>
            <li>Initial Item 4</li>
        </ol>
    </body>
```

The javascript:

```
// helper function for prepend() and append()
function makeNewLI(txt)
{
    var newItem = document.createElement("LI");
    newItem.innerHTML = txt;
    return newItem;
}

function replaceFirst(form)
{
    var newItem = makeNewLI(form.input.value)
    var firstLI = document.getElementById('myList').firstChild.value;
    document.getElementById('myList').replaceChild(newItem, firstLI);
}
```

I thought if I entered some text in the text box and clicked the Replace First Item button that the first item in the list would be replaced.  However, the first time I do that it is prepended to the top of the list and the list now has 5 items.  Then if I change the text in the text box and click the Replace First Item button again the first item in the list is changed.

I don't understand why this is happening. I expected the replacement would happen whenever I clicked the button. I am working with Firefox 4 on Ubuntu 10.04. Also, if I try to replace the last item in the list result is the same as I outlined above.

Thanks,  Jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things wrong there. Firstly, you are selecting the `value` instead of the element with `var firstLI = document.getElementById('myList').firstChild.value;` so use `var firstLI = document.getElementById('myList').firstChild;` instead.

Secondly, believe it or not your `firstChild` is a `TextNode` with empty text with your current markup. Remove the empty space between `<ol>` and the first `<li>` so that its `<ol><li>....`, like here:

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/5anyq/

Comment: Thanks, that works.  The firstChild.value was not the authors fault, I was experimenting and forgot to remove it, my bad.  The <ol> <li> formatting was straight from the book and I would have never figured that out on my own, thanks.

Comment: @Cleanman2 a quick way to debug these kinds of problems is to use `console.log(variable)` to see what exactly is getting gathered, as it displays elements, objects, arrays etc.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Learning lots of useful stuff today, glad I found this resource.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. You need to pass the node, not the `value` property (which doesn't even exist).
2. The first child is a text node, not the element (it's white space to be precise).  You could either remove the white space or replace the call to `firstChild` with the more reliable `.getElementsByTagName('li')[0]`.

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zm24r/1/)

---

[Some browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_traversal.html#t01) support [`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.firstElementChild), which does what it says on the tin. For maximum efficiency, you could do this:

```
var list = document.getElementById('myList');
var firstLI = list.firstElementChild || list.getElementsByTagName('li')[0];
```